# pfsense port-security limit mac to 1 (any mac allowed)

Tags: switch, hp-procurve

I am trying to set up HP procurve routers (25xx and 26xx) with port-security. Goal is to allow client devices and routers. But to disallow a switch, AP or a router in bridge mode. This should be accomplished by:

- Limit MAC to 1 per switch port at any given time
- Any MAC is allowed (as long as just one at the time)
- It is OK to change device/MAC at any time

I have not tried yet. But is this accomplished doing this in the web interface security -> port-security (or similar cli command)

```
learn-mode: static
address-limit: 1
Violation Action: none
```

I am quite sure that it will limit the port to only 1 MAC. But will that be remembered "static" when the user change to another device?

**Updated with solution, version 2**

It need to be learn mode : limited-continuous.
Action: none

It works just fine. It can be done from CLI for multiple ports at once. This line for port 1-23:

```
port-security 1-23 address-limit 1 learn-mode limited-continuous action none
```

About limited-continuous:
http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Switches-Hubs-Modems-Legacy-ITRC/port-security-learn-mode-limited-continuous/td-p/5179211#.Vd3CL5ej_1Q

> If 'limited-continuous' is specified, the first 'address-limit' source
>   MAC addresses heard on this port become the authorized addresses. When
>   new authorized addresses are learned, they are stored in a table. When
>   the table has reached its 'address-limit', any new source MAC
>   addresses received on the port constitutes an intrusion. The
>   authorized addresses in this mode will age out of the system,
>   therefore the list of authorized addresses can be dynamic over time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On page 9-10 of the manual it states that: This implies that the mac address limit will be reached, and will be remembered until flushed out manually.

**A port in Static learn mode (learn-mode static)
retains a learned MAC address even if you later reboot the switch or disableport security for that port:**

*From documentation:*

You can authorize specific
devices for the port, while still allowing the port to accept
other, non-specified devices until the port reaches the
configured address limit.

*This leads me to believe that you can set the port limit at 1 and have it act the way you intend it to.*

*However, this sentence:*

the port fills the
remainder of the address allowance with MAC addresses
it automatically learns

Leads me to believe the oposite. This is probably where the confusion is arising from. **My advice would be to set it up on one port and try it, see what happens, and you'll have a definitive answer**, this vagueness is rather annoying.

Comment: sorry, I should link to the documentation in the even anyone else wants to read through :
http://ftp.hp.com/pub/networking/software/Security-Oct2005-59906024-Chap09-Port_Security.pdf

Comment: Thanks. I will get one of these into the office next week and try it out.

Comment: Hi. It seems to work just fine. in CLI run "show config" and the port will list the MAC that is connected. Is a client removed, then "show config" will lst no MAC. So if no static MAC is set for the port it is updated dynamically.

Comment: Nope... seems that the static does remember the last MAC and a new MAC is not allowed

Comment: solved. Question updated on with the right info.